# Not retaining default position of modal box after dragging and closing

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap3 modal box and i have made it draggable using jquery UI draggable plugin. My issues is when i open the modal box first time it positioned center of the page and when i drag it and close the modal box, it retain the last dragged position while opening next time.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#modal").draggable({
       handle: ".modal-header"
   });
  
});
```

Comment: provide complete working code sample

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI Draggable sets the top and left positions.  To reset, trap the on close event and reset the top and left to 0.

Like this:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $(this).css({top:0,left:0});
})
```

Or see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinorodrigues/j4fj4ne2/1/) for an example.